# Sharding in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I try to test sharding in MongoDB. For example, I use host1.com and host2.com instead real server names.

So I created config server at host1.com:

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/configdb/ --configsvr
```

Started `mongos` at the same machine:

```
mongos --configdb host1.com --port 27020
```

And started `mongod` at two machines (host1.com and host2.com):

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/test_shard_db/ --shardsvr
```

I added shards, enabled sharding for database `test` and collection `test` with shard key {'name': 1} (collection has only this field and `_id` for test) as explained in tutorial . But after all this operations all my data writes only to one shard, which is primary for database.

Here is config:

Sharding status:

```
mongos> db.printShardingStatus()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: { "_id" : 1, "version" : 3 }
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "host1.com:27018",  "maxSize" : NumberLong(1) }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "host2.com:27018",  "maxSize" : NumberLong(10) }
  databases:
        ...
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        test.test chunks:
                shard0001   1
            { "name" : { $minKey : 1 } } -->> { "name" : { $maxKey : 1 } } on : shard0001 Timestamp(1000, 0)
```

Collection stats:

```
mongos> db.printCollectionStats()
test
{
    "sharded" : false,
    "primary" : "shard0000",
    "size" : 203535788,
    ...
}
```

Balancer status:

```
mongos> sh.isBalancerRunning()
true
```

So why all data in collection reside only at one shard though I added more than 1 megabyte of data? And why `db.printCollectionStats()` show me that `test` database `"sharded" : false`. What I did wrong?

Comment: The default chunk size is 64MB so you have room to grow before a split  will occur. You can split the shard key range yourself beforehand which can allow writes to go to multiple shards from the start. See the following for more info: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/#split-chunks

Comment: @James Wahlin, so shard maxSize and chunkSize are not correlated with each other?

Comment: maxSize will limit the volume of data on a given shard. When reached the balancer will look to move chunks to a shard where maxSize has not been reached. A chunk is a collection of documents that all fall within a section of the shard key range. The MongoDB balancer will move data between shards at the chunk level to balance. When a chunk approaches the maxSize value, it will be split into 2 which may result in a move.

Comment: The fact that you have `"primary" : "shard0000"` and `test.test chunks: shard0001 1` for status output verifies that the primary is on 0000 and the single shard on 0001. Another method to double check is to verify that there is an index over `name` field: if your collection is empty, it is automatically created. If however it's not empty, sharding is not going to happen

Comment: @James Wahlin, thanks!! You can post the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default chunk size is 64MB so you have room to grow before a split will occur. You can split the shard key range yourself beforehand which can allow writes to go to multiple shards from the start. See the [MongoDB Split Chunks documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/#split-chunks) for more info.

On the difference between chunk size and maxSize:

maxSize will limit the volume of data on a given shard. When reached the balancer will look to move chunks to a shard where maxSize has not been reached. A chunk is a collection of documents that all fall within a section of the shard key range. The MongoDB balancer will move data between shards at the chunk level to balance. When a chunk approaches the maxSize value, it will be split into 2 which may result in a move.