# Sharding & Replication in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, sharding, replicaset

First of all, I'm a beginner in mongoDB so please be patient with me. I'm using windows and I created a simple database that contains 4 collections. When I'm dealing with mongoDB, I first run: `mongod.exe --dbpath "Path To Data Folder"` in a terminal and then I connect to the mongod using `mongo.exe`. What I'm supposed to do is to distribute the database along with its collections into shards and replica sets for supporting distributed queries.

I tried to use commands like `sh.enableSharding("DATABASE NAME")` but it didn't work. I then figured out that I need to run mongos instead of mongod, so I followed this: [Sharding in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813194/sharding-in-mongodb) but unfortunately I didn't succeeded. I also did some research but it seems there is a lack of to-the-point guides on sharding and replication. So if you point me to the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Follow MongoDB docs on [Replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#deploy-a-replica-set) and [Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't enable sharding on a single database instance. You need to have at least 3 config server instances, two database (mongod) instances and a router instance (mongos). All of them should be running in the same time (i.e **don't close** the terminals in which you started all your instances).

A good starting point for you is to read the sharding tutorial in [Deploy a Sharded Cluster - MongoDB.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)